# how to make a vb program register form

Tags: vb.net

How do i make a vb program register form? like you can in steam, google, Xbox live? Register on one computer and login from another Computer? For Free? Is i could like in drop box etc? I am making a game launcher program and i want to have theme sync there stuff. I Googled it no help! The only way i know how to is a offline account.  It is annoying me. I am not that good in vb.net programming. Thanks!

here is my code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Settings.sli Then
            Main.show()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            My.Settings.sli = 1
        Else
            My.Settings.sli = 0

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        My.Settings.user = TextBox3.Text
        My.Settings.pass = TextBox4.Text
        My.Settings.Save()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If My.Settings.user = TextBox1.Text And TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.pass Then
            Main.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Username Or Password Wrong! Try Again!")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks!

Comment: i think you should deploy your database online.

Comment: what database should i use?

Comment: your current database. so you can save and retrieve your database online. Try these [free SQL hosting](http://freehosting1.net/free_mssql_hosting.aspx)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not suitable for questions like this. This is not a coding service and not a "help me find this thing"-service. Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site where we help with **specific** programming related problems/questions, which can be answered in a somewhat short manner. I suggest you read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [On-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).